# How to prevent NestedScrollView from scrolling if body is small?

Tags: flutter

How do I prevent a `NestedScrollView` from scrolling the `headerSliverBuilder` when the `body` is small?

In the following example, I want to prevent the `SliverAppBar` from being scrollable if the `body` does not require scrolling, because it is small, i.e. in this example, the view should not scroll at all, but it does.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: NestedScrollView(
      headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
        return <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            title: Text('Demo'),
            expandedHeight: 300,
          )
        ];
      },
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Container(color: Colors.red, height: 100),
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Container(color: Colors.amber, height: 100),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

The problem can be solved by moving the `SliverAppBar` into the `CustomScrollView` and not use the `NestedScrollView` at all. This is not a solution for me though, because https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12033 basically requires me to use a `NestedScrollView`.

Comment: have you found the solution?? please tell me

Comment: No, I switched to `CustomScrollView` after getting https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/55829 merged.

Comment: Wrap the content in a SliverFillRemaining widget

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the content in a SliverFillRemaining widget:
Wrap your content in a SliverFillRemaining widget. This widget ensures that the content takes up all available space in the NestedScrollView, preventing scrolling when the content is small.

```
NestedScrollView(
headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
// Your sliver app bar(s) here
// ...
},
  body: SliverFillRemaining(
  child: YourContentWidget(), // Replace with your content widget
 ),
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Nested extends StatefulWidget {
  const Nested({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Nested> createState() => _NestedState();
}

class _NestedState extends State<Nested> {
  late final ScrollController controller;
  ScrollPhysics scrollPhysics = const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = ScrollController();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      if (controller.position.maxScrollExtent <= 0) {
        scrollPhysics = const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NestedScrollView(
      controller: controller,
      physics: scrollPhysics,
      headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) => [
        SliverAppBar(
          title: const Text('App Bar'),
          expandedHeight: 200,
          pinned: true,
          forceElevated: innerBoxIsScrolled,
        ),
      ],
      body: ListView(),
    );
  }
}
```

This is an example how you can disable scrolling while the list is small.
This can be used in any listviews.. Comment if you have any doubts.

Answer (score 0):

On way of preventing `NestedScrollView` from scrolling is by listening to the `NestedViewScroll` scroll event and figuring out the size(height) of the `CustomScrollView's` body and based on that, we can calculate and decide.
If the sizes are known at compile time then the it's very simple, but if the sizes are dynamic, then it get's little complex. I have assumed complex scenario and modified your example with the approach I made. Would be glad if someone could figure out a more simpler approach. This [blog](https://blog.gskinner.com/archives/2021/01/flutter-how-to-measure-widgets.html) helped me figuring out how to calculate dynamic sizes.
Also during debugging, make sure to hot restart or rerun.
If the sizes are know at compile time, then we don't need `MeasurableWidget`
You can view [shared code here.](https://dartpad.dev/?id=c1a85157e6808427ebccc84a365f65c8).

> **Please note**: Mesaurable widget is re-rendered every time when it's first rendered to figure out it's height. You can refer to this
> [blog](https://blog.gskinner.com/archives/2021/01/flutter-how-to-measure-widgets.html)
> for more details.

`main.dart` file

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});


  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final _nestedController = ScrollController();
  final _nestedScrollGlobalKey = GlobalKey<NestedScrollViewState>();
  final _customScrollGlobalKey = GlobalKey();
  // this will save height of each child in a map
  final _customBodyChildrenSizes = <int,double>{};
  final double _expandedHeight = 300;


  void nestedScrollListener() {
    final height = _nestedScrollGlobalKey.currentContext?.size?.height??0;

    double bodyHeight = 0;
    ScrollDirection scrollDirection = _nestedController.position.userScrollDirection;
    _customBodyChildrenSizes.forEach((key, value) =>bodyHeight += value);
    if (scrollDirection == ScrollDirection.reverse && (bodyHeight  + _expandedHeight) <= height) {
      _nestedController.jumpTo(0);
    }
  }

  void onSized(int index, Size size) {
    _customBodyChildrenSizes[index] = size.height;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
     super.initState();
     _nestedController.addListener(nestedScrollListener);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _nestedController.removeListener(nestedScrollListener);
    _nestedController.dispose();
    _customBodyChildrenSizes.clear();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: NestedScrollView(
          key: _nestedScrollGlobalKey,
          controller: _nestedController,
          headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
            return <Widget>[
              SliverAppBar(
                title: Text('Demo'),
                 expandedHeight: _expandedHeight,
              )
            ];
          },
          body: CustomScrollView(
            key: _customScrollGlobalKey,
            slivers: <Widget>[
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: MeasurableWidget(
                    onSized: (Size size){onSized(0, size);},
                    child: Container(color: Colors.red, height: 100)),
              ),
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: MeasurableWidget(
                    onSized: (Size size){onSized(1, size);},
                    child: Container(color: Colors.red, height: 100)),
              ),
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: MeasurableWidget(
                    onSized: (Size size){onSized(2, size);},
                  child: Container(color: Colors.amber, height: 100),),
              ),
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: MeasurableWidget(
                    onSized: (Size size){onSized(3, size);},
                  child: Container(color: Colors.blue, height: 100),),
              ),
              // SliverToBoxAdapter(
              //   child: MeasurableWidget(
              //       onSized: (Size size){onSized(4, size);},
              //     child: Container(color: Colors.purple, height: 100),),
              // ),
              // SliverToBoxAdapter(
              //   child: MeasurableWidget(
              //     onSized: (Size size){onSized(5, size);},
              //     child: Container(color: Colors.brown, height: 300),),
              // ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}


class MeasurableWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MeasurableWidget({Key? key, required this.child, required this.onSized}) : super(key: key);
  final Widget child;
  final void Function(Size size) onSized;

  @override
  State<MeasurableWidget> createState() => _MeasurableWidgetState();
}

class _MeasurableWidgetState extends State<MeasurableWidget> {
  bool _hasMeasured = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final renderBox = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox?;
    if (renderBox != null) {
      Size size = renderBox.size;
      if (size != Size.zero) {
        widget.onSized.call(size);
      } else if (!_hasMeasured) {
        // Need to build twice in order to get size
        scheduleMicrotask(() => setState(()=>_hasMeasured = true));
      }
    } else {
        Future(() {
       scheduleMicrotask(() => setState(()=>_hasMeasured = 
    true));
      });
  }
    return widget.child;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should wrap your small widget/body with Expanded widget
@lalit-rawat

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

If the requirement is to lock the view from scrolling at all, you can try to consider using [`AbsorbPointer`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AbsorbPointer-class.html). Wrap it around your NestedScrollView.

```
AbsorbPointer( 
   isAbsorbing: true,
   child: NestedScrollView(...))
```

Or the neater way is to use `SliverPersistentHeader` and `_SliverAppBarDelegate`, Check out [this blog post](https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-collapsing-toolbar-sliver-app-bar-14b858e87abe) for a better view of details regarding this implementation.

Comment: I've spent a lot of time looking for the exact tutorial you've posted through this link. A lot of people who use the Silver App Bar want to do but don't know where to start.