# How to fix scrolling of TabBarView in CustomScrollView relative to content size?

Tags: flutter, flutter-scrollbar

The [flutter docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/lists/floating-app-bar) provides a nice example on how to have a floating app bar above a list using `CustomScrollView`. The code in their example exhibits exactly the behavior I want, that is, for the app bar to only scroll away when there is enough content to scroll. Below is a verbatim copy of the code with the exception of the `childCount` property of the `SliverList` set to a small number of items to demonstrate that no scrolling will occur in that case.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const title = 'Floating App Bar';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        // No appbar provided to the Scaffold, only a body with a
        // CustomScrollView.
        body: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            // Add the app bar to the CustomScrollView.
            const SliverAppBar(
              // Provide a standard title.
              title: Text(title),
              // Allows the user to reveal the app bar if they begin scrolling
              // back up the list of items.
              floating: true,
              // Display a placeholder widget to visualize the shrinking size.
              flexibleSpace: Placeholder(),
              // Make the initial height of the SliverAppBar larger than normal.
              expandedHeight: 200,
            ),
            // Next, create a SliverList
            SliverList(
              // Use a delegate to build items as they're scrolled on screen.
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                // The builder function returns a ListTile with a title that
                // displays the index of the current item.
                (context, index) => ListTile(title: Text('Item #$index')),
                // Builds 1000 ListTiles
                childCount: 3, //<------------- Adjusted to three items
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I would like to mimic exactly this behavior using a `TabBar` with a corresponding `TabBarView`. The problem is that the `TabBarView` scrolls unnecessarily when the content is small and overflows if its content is large. I've tried using a `NestedScrollView` following the [tutorial](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NestedScrollView-class.html) in the docs but the problem persists. I have currently resorted to the solution mentioned by the OP at the bottom of [their question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61126348/how-to-prevent-nestedscrollview-from-scrolling-if-body-is-small) where they suggest to nest the `SliverAppBar` within a `CustomScrollView`. This does not work either. Below is a simplified version of the code which illustrates the issue. Note that the contents of tab 1 and tab 2 scrolls unnecessarily while the contents of tab 3 overflows.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70338077/dynamic-scrolling-of-nestedscrollview-based-on-the-content-of-tabbarview) demonstrates [exactly what I'm after](https://dartpad.dev/?id=c961ac49049c7aae6d6e2c39dfd8aa27&null_safety=true) but does not use a `TabBarView` (which allows swiping to change tabs).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const NestedScrollViewExampleApp());

class NestedScrollViewExampleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const NestedScrollViewExampleApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(body: SafeArea(child: NestedScrollViewExample())),
    );
  }
}

class NestedScrollViewExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const NestedScrollViewExample({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverAppBar(
              title: const Text('Floating Nested SliverAppBar'),
              floating: true,
              pinned: false,
              expandedHeight: 200.0,
              forceElevated: false,
              bottom: TabBar(
                  tabs: ['tab1', 'tab2', 'tab3'].map((e) => Text(e)).toList()),
            ),
            const SliverFillRemaining(
              child: TabBarView(
                children: [Text('content1'), Text('content2'), _OverflowContent()],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _OverflowContent extends StatelessWidget {
  const _OverflowContent({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) ...[Text('Item $i')],
    ]);
  }
}
```

I think that the `CustomScrollView` needs to somehow be aware of the size of the `TabView`'s content, but I'm not sure if this is at all possible. My goal is to have a TabBarView with dynamically sized content within a scrolling view.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Edit Summary: 
This is a workaround that will set the scroll property of the NestedScrollView based on the number of items that need to be shown.

I used a NestedScrollView with a TickerProviderStateMixIn
**scrollOrNot()** determines the scroll physics based on the number of  items.
Any list with less than 5 items will not be scrollable. 
**tabContent()** returns a sliverlist for each tab in the TabBarView

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      
      home:  HomePage());
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});
  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
 late TabController tabController; // TabController used to control both the TabBar and TabBarView
 int selectedIndex=0; // a variable that tracks the tab that is tapped.
 List<int> childCount=[2,3,100]; // a list of the number of items in each TabBarView
 
 @override
 void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    tabController=TabController(length: 3, vsync: this,
    // I tried setting the animation duration to 0, but 
    // any animation takes time.
    // generally speaking, swiping is slower than tapping. 
    animationDuration: const Duration(microseconds: 0)

    
    ); // initializing the TabController
// setting a listener that will check for changes in the tabs
    tabController.addListener(() {
//setState() if the index stopped changing after a tap event
// this is useful for handling the tap event 
// but it does nothing for the swipe event which is automatically handled
// by the TabBarView
if(!tabController.indexIsChanging){
  setState(() { selectedIndex=tabController.index;});

} });
  
  }

// a method that determines the scroll physics of a list based
// on the number of items it is required to show. 
// any list with less than 5 items will not be allowed to scroll
  scrollOrNot({required int numOfChildren}){
    if(numOfChildren<5){ return const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics();}
    else{return const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics();}
  }

  // a method that dynamically creates sliverlists based on the 
  // the number of required items
  tabContent({required int numOfChildren}){
    return Scaffold(body:
  CustomScrollView(
  physics: scrollOrNot(numOfChildren: numOfChildren),
    slivers:[
   SliverList.builder(
    itemCount: numOfChildren,
    itemBuilder: (context, index)=> ListTile(title: Text("item $index"),))
 
  ])
  );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  NestedScrollView(
      // determining the scroll physics based on the number of children
      // childCount is the list from above
      physics: scrollOrNot(numOfChildren: childCount[selectedIndex]),
headerSliverBuilder:(context, innerBoxIsScrolled)=>[
 SliverAppBar(
  expandedHeight: 300,
  floating: true,
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  title: 
//Note that the delay in changing the index is due to the animation duration
//I tried to make it 0 milliseconds but swiping is always slower than tapping  
Text("tabControllerIndex: ${tabController.index}"),
  bottom: TabBar(

    controller: tabController,
    indicatorColor: Colors.red,
    tabs: const [Text("Tab 1"),Text("Tab 2"),Text("Tab 3")]),
)
],
body:
 TabBarView(
  controller: tabController,
  children: [
    // creating the sliverlists using the tabContent method
  tabContent(numOfChildren: childCount[0]),
  tabContent(numOfChildren: childCount[1]),
  tabContent(numOfChildren: childCount[2]),
])

);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But this is similar to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70338077/dynamic-scrolling-of-nestedscrollview-based-on-the-content-of-tabbarview) I pointed to. I'd like to make use of `TabBarView` since it allows one to swipe to change tabs.

Comment: @john2048 Please check my edited answer. You will notice a better performance with tapping, but swiping also works here. Let me know if this is works for you.